# STM32 HAL DMA interrupt does not fire

Tags: interrupt, stm32, dma, hal

I'm doing an STM32 HAL course.

In the section "Direct Memory Access (DMA)", the interrupt doesn't get fired on completion of the DMA transfer.
In polling mode all works fine.
I use a Nucleo-F746ZG, my code is on github: https://github.com/bkht/STM32-HAL-DMA-Interrupt

What could I check to fix this?

When setting up the callback function, does it need to go before calling HAL_DMA_Init?
Or can it be done just before starting the DMA transfer with HAL_DMA_Start?
Also, I do see the & sometimes, referring to the function address, I tried it, but it didn't make a difference.
What should be used, `&` or `not`?

```
/* Setup callbacks, not sure this can be done without HAL_DMA_Init */
hdma_memtomem_dma2_stream0.XferCpltCallback = &XferCpltCallback;
```

Comment: Hi, I monitored the DMA interrupt flags as follows:
In Keil uVision, when in debugging mode, I selected Menu →​ ​Peripherals →​ System Viewer →​ DMA →​ DMA2.

After starting the DMA tansfer (HAL_DMA_Start​), I can see the correct flags were set in LISR:
TCIF0 - Stream 0 transfer complete interrupt flag​
HTIF0 - Stream 0 half transfer interrupt flag​ (expected as well)
But the ISR XferCpltCallback​ did not fire.

I'm struggling to get this working. Does anybody know how to approach this further?
Kind regards, Jack.

Comment: Now I also tried this on a STM32F407VG Discovery board, where the interrupts also do not fire. Therefore, I think is is not a bug in HAL. I must be doing something wrong, I guess.

Comment: I solved the issue and fixed the code (on github), I called HAL_DMA_Start() function instead of HAL_DMA_Start_IT() function, when trying to use the DMA interrupt.

Comment: Why don't you just reply to your own question with the solution? You are allowed to do this if I am not mistaken. This way the question will appear closed.

Comment: For the benefit of future troubleshooters: I had a similar problem that turned out to be caused by `MX_LPUART1_UART_Init` (which set up the DMA channels) getting called before `MX_DMA_Init` (which enables the DMA clock), which was frustrating because STM32CubeIDE (1.7.0) generated them in that order in my case.

Answer (score 1):

Pulling [@jacobq](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1171509/jacobq) comment into an answer.

There is currently a bug in the CubeMX autogenerated code where the `MX_DMA_Init()` is called in the wrong order.

The [proposed solution](https://community.st.com/s/question/0D53W00001EzCmCSAV/mxdmainit-order-in-the-mainc-file-generated-by-stm32cubemx-how-to-fix) is to edit the `ioc` file, where it lists the function order.
[image: ProjectManager.functionlistsort]

This is needed because the CubeMX software (in Project Manager > Advanced Settings) locks the position of the `MX_DMA_Init` generated function call unhelpfully!

[image: CubeMX Software]